# Faster way to grep from large dataset (~200 GB total)

Tags: linux, terminal, grep, dataset

I am trying to replicate results of a paper (https://www.computer.org/csdl/pds/api/csdl/proceedings/download-article/12OmNz61doX/pdf) and the dataset provided contains Netflow data (router-based summaries of IP data). Example:

```
118902,64766,Comp364445,Comp634161,17,Port02221,Port28366,12749,15620,1070916,1437040
118902,81270,Comp364445,Comp634161,17,Port02221,Port28366,15799,19759,1327116,1817828
118902,86850,Comp364445,Comp634161,17,Port02221,Port28366,16996,21137,1427664,1944604
118903,15280,Comp364445,Comp372656,17,Port90832,Port28366,2696,3219,226464,296148
118903,28228,Comp364445,Comp372656,17,Port90832,Port28366,5459,6438,458556,592296
118903,49709,Comp364445,Comp372656,17,Port90832,Port28366,9292,11955,780528,1099860
...
```

There are 20 files containing ~10 GB each of this kind of data. I am interested in the third and fourth columns - source and destination machines. I have a file of 43 src/dest. pairs and want to extract the rows that contain these pairs.

I am currently trying to do this with the grep command. Using `LC_ALL=C fgrep -Fw -f edges.csv test_dataset`, where edges.csv is the file of src/dest. pairs and test_dataset is a shortened file from one day (from about 1 billion lines to 100,000 lines), it takes ~45 seconds to run, meaning it would take 3-4 days to grep through one single days dataset. Is there a faster way to do this?

edges.csv format:

```
Comp5736,Comp8643
Comp875,Comp3468
Comp7854,Comp5720
Comp15860,Comp1685
Comp4509,Comp1685
Comp3605,Comp1685
Comp11232,Comp1685
Comp12380,Comp1685
Comp8964,Comp1685
Comp27192,Comp1685
...
```

Comment: What if you add a comma to end of each line of `edges.csv` and drop the `-w`?

Comment: @Shawn removing the `-w` sped it up a bit but changing `edges.csv` in addition to that actually seemed to make it run slower. I ran each command once only.